# Installing .NET 4 Beta 2 results in Access Denied

Tags: installation, .net-framework

I'm getting an Error Code 5: Access Denied error when trying to install .NET 4 Beta 2.

The machine is Windows 7 x64 (RTM), I'm a local admin with UAC as off as it can be. The error log gives me no more information that that error...

I've already installed it successfully on two other machines so far, it's just the one that's failing.

Can anyone shed any light on the problem?

(It's being installed from the extracted DVD from MSDN, the same copy that was used on the other two machines. It was extracted to the desktop and I tried moving it to the root - still nothing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was the read-only Mac OSX drive (thanks to BootCamp)...removed the drive letter and all was good!